# proving that the signum function does not have an antiderivative on the real number line

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

so I have to prove that the signum function does not have an antiderivative on R.

I wrote the function down. Then took the integral of $1$ which was equal to $x$, $-1$, when $f(x)=-1$, and $C$, when $x= 0$. I really have no idea how to prove that a function does not have an antiderivative and I don't know what I'm doing. Could you please give some advice or show how I can solve this?
Thank you very much.

P.S. Can a discountinous function have an antiderivative on R?
I have just started learning about integration.

Comment: Darboux's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) says that a derivative has the intermediate value property, that the signup function does not have. It is a little bit an overkill for your first question, but applying it to the differentiable but not $C^1$ function $x\mapsto x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ gives a positive answer to your last question.

Comment: @Balloon Thanks!

Comment: Think of $f(x) = |x|$ for $x\neq 0$. If $x<0$ then $f(x) = -x$, implying $f'(x)=-1$ for $x<0$. If $x>0$ then $f(x)=x$ implying $f'(x)=1$ for $x>0$. Thus, $f'(x) = \text{signum}(x)$ for $x\neq 0$. Now, what happens at $x=0$? the simple explanation is that since $\{0\}$ contains a single point, the integral doesn't really care. No matter how you define $\text{signum}(0)$, its anti-derivative is still $|x|$. This means that $f'(0)$ is undefined by convention. But, depending on the context, $\text{signum}(0) = 0$, a different constant, or even a whole interval $[-1,1]$ (in non-smooth analysis).